# How can an attribute-buffing item be modelled?

Tags: besm

I am preparing a modern supernatural/martial arts game using BESM 3rd edition and want to offer my players a buffer archetype. While I have the concept and nature of the buffs, I can't figure out how to make it work when it comes to buying those attributes.

**What I have so far**

The concept would be that buffs are represented by talismans that could be knocked out by called shots and protected by the PC. The buffs themselves would be based on existing attributes keeping a relatively low-fantasy scope.

The closest so far appears to be the Transfer attributes, which allows a character to gift one of his own attributes to someone else. Which doesn't quite have the flavour I want.

The clearest idea so far is to have the player take the Transfer attribute as a way to gauge the power level of the buff. Each level giving them a two points  to buy attributes for the buff. Using it would then work as using a weapon with preparation (requires a full action and forbids defense for one round) and limited ammo (possibly 6 times between long rest to give two rounds of buff for the whole party).

The player would have access to a short list of buffs of similar power level. This is based on another custom rule for weapons.

**The problem I have with this:**

While the idea I described above makes sense to me, I'm afraid I am missing an easier way to make it work. Just reading the above descriptions makes me nervous about pitching it to my players.

The price of making a buffer as per RAW also seems incredibly expensive. For example, using the textbook rules of Transfer, it takes 25 points to create something as simple as a +3 to combat value as a non-stacking buff. Taking +3x5 points for the Transfer and +9 points for the +3 combat value.

Another thing that I don't like is the fact that the user has to buy the attributes themselves. Which makes it so that an old shrine lady might need to have +3 to melee combat value to give the buff. Which may not makes sense.

So, based on experience with BESM or similar systems, is there a way to create such a character that adds as few house-rules as possible and doesn't overly inflate the cost of the character?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I thought I'd record how I fixed this.

Turns out that there are 2 mechanics that work for this :

1. A character attribute called Transfer allows a character to gift
   one of his own attributes to a target. It's not quite clear to me how
   this works per RAW, since I've used the following solution.
2. An attribute can have a modifier called Imbue which basically
   says "this is a buff". Other modifiers are used to add a cast time,
   energy cost and charges/day. Also a custom modifier that represents
   the fact it can be removed via called shot.